# Pegar valor de um input especifico usando AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Seguinte, tenho um form que será enviado com AJAX, porém a URL irá variar de acordo com o ID, exemplo:

```
site.com/ajax/remove/100 <- ID
site.com/ajax/remove/200 <- ID
```

Este valor do ID está num campo hidden do formulário, como posso pegar este valor e passar para o ajax? exemplo do código:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#send_request').submit(function() {

        var dados = jQuery(this).serialize();
        //var id = 

        jQuery.ajax({

            url : 'site.com/'+id,
            dataType : 'JSON',
            type : "POST",
            data : dados,
            success : function(response) {
                //alert(response.message);
                if (response.success == 1) {
                    //tudo ok
                } else {
                    //deu ruim,zé
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#send_request').submit(function() {

        var dados = jQuery(this).serialize();
        var id = $("#campo-hidden").val(); /// <<<<<

        jQuery.ajax({

            url : 'site.com/'+id,
            dataType : 'JSON',
            type : "POST",
            data : dados,
            success : function(response) {
                //alert(response.message);
                if (response.success == 1) {
                    //tudo ok
                } else {
                    //deu ruim,zé
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```